# How can I import specific columns from csv file to python?

Tags: python

[python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA9OJ.png)

what syntax should i use in importing only the columns of 'location', specifically two countries only ,'date', 'total_cases', 'new_cases', 'total_deaths', 'new_deaths'.

Comment: You can use "usecols" parameter from : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the pandas library for handling the csv.

You can use `read_csv()` to skip/select rows based on a conditional format.

Here is a link with a step-by-step guide on how to do this:

https://datascientyst.com/read_csv-skip-rows-condition-values-pandas/amp/

Alternatively, you can import the entire `.csv` file and then delete certain rows based on a condition, as seen in the link below:

https://towardsdatascience.com/delete-row-from-pandas-dataframes-based-on-column-value-4b18bb1eb602

Comment: OP wants to read certain columns only, he is not asking to delete certain rows.

Comment: yeah. what specific code should I use to read certain columns with conditions?